# Fetch Static Records in the Memory Cache

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, memory

For small sets of data that are infrequently updated such as lookup values,I want to build a method of caching them in memory on my application server rather than constantly querying
them in the database.
The best approach that i have is hold them in a static field in my application :

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static List<UserRoles> userRolesList;
}
protected void Application_Start()
{
  //some stuff
  MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
  MyClass.userRolesList = db.UserRoles.ToList();
  //...
}
```

Is there a better approach for the goal?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree that static variables on the client are the best place to store small information sets such as lookups.

For large sets I would query from the server with clauses and avoid storing in static memory. You could however take the entire set from the server and store in a local cache such as Isolated Storage or on Disk.

One coding suggestion for your client, put a public struct (ClientData) in your main app. (e.g. for WPF/Silverlight)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   public struct ClientData
   {
      public static bool IsInitialized = false;
      public static ObservableCollection<string> DataTypes;
      public static Dictionary<int, CategoryType> CategoryLookup;
   }
}
```

Then you can access your static data throughout the program like this:

```
if (App.ClientData.IsInitialized)
{
   DataList.ItemsSource = App.ClientData.CategoryLookup;
}
```